# How to open a new window in react-native-windows?

Tags: react-native, uwp

I'm developing a UWP (Windows) application using **React-Native-Windows**. What I'm trying to do is open a new window by pressing a button. And I want to invoke a method in the main window after closing the pop-up window. What is the best way to achieve these requirements? Is there a library that I can use to achieve this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Comment: @AnmolMishra Hi! `Windows.open()` works fine in ReactJS. But I just can't find a way to use it in **ReactNative** to open a new application screen in a new window. It would be very helpful if you can give me some directive in this regard.